# Composer.lock does not match project versions

Tags: composer

I have a drupal site developed using the [core-recommended](https://github.com/drupal/core-recommended) project, and I maintain the site using the [recommended practices](https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer) on drupal.org.

Recently after adding a new developer to the project, Composer is now showing the wrong versions of modules and not updating them.

For example, with the Font Awesome module:

1. Composer.lock shows version 2.26 is installed.
2. `composer info drupal/fontawesome` shows 2.26 and displays the correct path under /web/modules/contrib/fontawesome
3. But /web/modules/contrib/fontawesome/fontawesome.info.yml shows version 2.25
4. Even worse, /vendor/drupal/fontawesome/fontawesome.info.yml shows version 2.23
5. `composer install --dry-run` returns "Nothing to install, update or remove"

I've tried searching the web for this issue and have so far come up empty.

I've also tried deleting the composer.lock file and running a fresh `composer install` but it ends up in the same state afterwards.

Has anyone run into this problem, or have an idea how to fix it?

Edit to add my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "drupal/block_class": "^2.0",
        "drupal/colorbox": "^2.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.2",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.2",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.2",
        "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.4",
        "drupal/file_browser": "^1.3",
        "drupal/filefield_sources": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/fontawesome": "^2.19",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^4.0",
        "drupal/google_api_client": "^4.0",
        "drupal/google_cse": "^3.7",
        "drupal/honeypot": "^2.0",
        "drupal/ldap": "^4.2",
        "drupal/metatag": "^1.22",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.8",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.6",
        "drupal/restrict_ip": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/site_alert": "^1.2",
        "drupal/token": "^1.9",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.1",
        "drupal/webform_googlesheets": "^2.0",
        "drupal/wysiwyg_mediaembed": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drush/drush": "^10.6",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^2.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        },
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "web/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the commit history to find out what the new developer changed?

Comment: Please post your composer.json

Comment: Are modules being checked into source control, or do you have a build system set up that all the developers are using in common?  For example, if you are committing modules into git and there is no clear process for doing so, you might get a mess like this.

Comment: What seems to be working is to manually restore pieces of my composer.lock file for the dependencies that have become unsynced. Then I can run `composer install` and it succesfully "downgrades" to the correct versions. Then I can run `composer update drupal/module` and it actually updates the module.

Comment: It sounds like you just have stale files in the install folders - `rm -rf vendor web/modules/contrib web/core web/libraries` then `composer install`, that should sort it

Comment: Also if you've been manually editing composer.lock it would be best to restore/delete that too before installing